# how to attch and see subversion source code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

We are working on a internal tool to extend the functionality of Subversion.
In-order to develop it we seek to look at the source code of subversion so that we can know class to use.
So provided I have the src with me, how can we attach the source code in eclipse.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want exactly ? see the source code of svn ? Or install your custom plugin in eclipse, so you can use it ?

Comment: See the source code of svn in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To see the svn source code :

```
Right click in workspace > Import > Plug-ins & fragments :
```

- The active target Platform
- Select from all plug-ins and fragments
- Import As : Project with source folders

`hit Next`

Select `org.eclipse.team.svn*` plugins and `add` them in the right part

`hit Finish`